# Life cycle of an application: how do I manage the updates

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have 2 apps published but I don't know how to manage the life cycle of the application. For example if I have a bug, the way I do it now: once I have a correction for the bug I go into studio->file->project structure->flavors, I increment the version code, then build the APK. Then I go into GPC->APK menu,upload new APK to prod.

I think this is not the right way to do. It obliges the user to un-install and re-install.

How do I manage updates?

How do I manage patches?

Sorry about the dumb questions. I've searched for docs but struggle to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are doing it correctly.

Whenever you fix any bug or add a new feature and feel that your app is ready to be updated in Play Store, **you need to increment your `versionCode` and `versionName`.**

Now, you need to open Google Play Console and upload the new APK. Incrementing the versionCode is mandatory for Google Play to consider it as an update.

Don't worry, **the users will not need to uninstall the old app and reinstall the new app manually**. Everything is handled seamlessly by the Google Play app installed on the user's device.

And the users also don't download the entire app after every update. **Google now uses File-by-File patching to reduce the app update size drastically**. So, in simple words, the users only download the changed and they get patched automatically.

**EDIT**

You need to increment the `versionCode` for the updates to happen. The `versionName` is only shown to the user so that they can understand that it is an update over the previous version. The versionCode is used for internal purposes and is not shown to the user.

Ex - If your versionCode is 10, you can increment it to 11 for an update to happen, even if the versionName is not changed at all. But it is RECOMMENDED to change the versionName in accordance with the versionCode so that your users can understand that you have updated the app.

Comment: I was changing the version code but the version name. Has the version name has to have a relationship to version code. For ex: I have a version code of 3 and avre

Comment: Typo... And a version name 1.3.ex. I correct a bug: I move to version code 4 and version name 1.4.ex ?

Comment: I have updated the answer. If your problem is solved, please accept the answer.

Comment: I'm testing at the moment :)